# Catching database errors/exceptions in Quarkus ORM with Panache

Tags: exception, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a question regarding Quarkus that has to do with Hibernate with Panache: I really love the concept and I never miss an occasion to use it but always stumble upon the problem when I have an Exception, like a unique constraint violation or anything that has to do with the database.
How do you proceed on catching them so they won't spoil my application by throwing an Exception to goes up unto the frontend for example?
A code like for example "member.persist()" throws no particular exception that can be explicitly caught if I check the code/implementation of it.

D.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd like to mention that catching JPA exceptions with a try/catch is dodgy at best:

1. Most of these exceptions result from an incorrect configuration and/or an IO error, so you can consider those exceptions a server error (HTTP 500).
2. Most of the time you can't recover from such exception without restarting the whole transaction/session: Hibernate `Session` are generally considered unusable after an exception was thrown.

Generally I'd recommend you avoid the exception altogether, by checking that what you're doing will actually work. E.g. to avoid a constraint violation, try to fetch the association/entity you're persisting first, and if it already exists then throw a proper exception yourself, one that has meaning for business users.

If you can't avoid the exception, in very specific cases, you could try to recover by trying a slightly different approach. The key is to do that in a separate transaction, which means you must not start the transaction immediately in your endpoint.

I can't give you a precise solution as you didn't mention what you were trying to achieve exactly, but I can give you some generic code.

Either use the `@Transactional` annotation on non-private methods that you delegate to:

```java
@Path("/endpoint")
public class Endpoint {

    @PUT
    // NOT @Transactional
    public String doSomething(Integer someData) {
        try {
            return doSomethingWithApproach1(someData);
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) { // Or whatever makes sense
            // You might need to catch PersistenceException instead
            // and do a if ( e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException )
            // Yes it's ugly, but then I told you it dodgy at best.
            return doSomethingWithApproach2(someData);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    protected String doSomethingWithApproach1(Integer someData) {
        // ...
    }

    @Transactional
    protected String doSomethingWithApproach2(Integer someData) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or use [`QuarkusTransaction`](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#programmatic-approach):

```java
@Path("/endpoint")
public class Endpoint {

    @PUT
    // NOT @Transactional
    public String doSomething(Integer someData) {
        try {
            return QuarkuTransaction.requiringNew().call( () -> doSomethingWithApproach1(someData) );
        } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) { // Or whatever makes sense
            // You might need to catch PersistenceException instead
            // and do a if ( e.getCause() instanceof ConstraintViolationException )
            // Yes it's ugly, but then I told you it dodgy at best.
            return QuarkuTransaction.requiringNew().call( () -> doSomethingWithApproach2(someData) );
        }
    }

    // NOT @Transactional
    protected String doSomethingWithApproach1(Integer someData) {
        // ...
    }

    // NOT @Transactional
    protected String doSomethingWithApproach2(Integer someData) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Now, if all you want is to display some error message in your HTTP response, then you can do that in RestEasy (classic or reactive) by registering an exception mapping. You can find documentation for RestEasy Reactive (the recommended way to do Rest in Quarkus) there: https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#exception-mapping . There is probably similar documentation for RestEasy Classic somewhere.

FWIW all JPA/Hibernate exceptions extend `jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException`, so you'd end up with something like this:

```java
class ExceptionMappers {
    @ServerExceptionMapper
    public RestResponse<String> mapException(jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException x) {
        return RestResponse.status(Response.Status.SERVER_ERROR, "Persistence exception: " + x.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I can't help but wonder why you would want to single out persistence exceptions from other `RuntimeException`s, though...